# Korean to English Seal translation

Tags: korean-to-english

I have a seal that I received from my fathers estate... I am not sure what it says. Is there a way someone can look at the picture and help with translating it for me? Please excuse my lack of skills on the picture but I am not sure how to go about loading this. Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: This question was answered from the migrated question, but I will add here that this image is upside down (lest anyone learning Korean be confused). (No worries for @Jody though--they have no point of reference).

Comment: 크리스랜달인. It looks lika a name. Chris Rendalin.